# IllegalArgumentException what could cause it besides type mismatch

Tags: java, illegalargumentexception

I'm getting this error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferTo<Unknown Source>
    at Program.insert<Program.java:14>
    at Program.main<Program.java:203>
```

The only thing I can think of is the argument types don't match. I checked the types that I was passing to the method, and they match. Is it possible that it's a problem to pass a FileChannel to a method? I didn't see anything in the documentation at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html

Here's the method in question:

`public static void insert (RandomAccessFile fileForInsertion, FileChannel srcChannel, FileChannel tgtChannel, long offset, byte[] content) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException`

This is line 14, inside the method:

```
    srcChannel.transferTo(offset, (filesize - offset), tgtChannel);
```

This is the call to the method, line 203:

```
    insert(rFile, sourceChannel, targetChannel, insertionIndex, textToInsertBytes);
```

Here's how the arguments passed were created:

```
    RandomAccessFile rFile = new RandomAccessFile(new File(rFileName), "rw");
    FileChannel sourceChannel = rFile.getChannel();
    FileChannel targetChannel = randomTemp.getChannel();
    long insertionIndex = 0;
    byte[] textToInsertBytes = new byte[0];
```

Am I missing something obvious here? As I check around on various sites for an answer, I notice that some error messages give a reason, like "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The parent path cannot be null." However, my message doesn't have that. What else could be the problem?

Comment: If the argument types didn't match, you'd get a *complie-time* error. I'd normally expect an `IllegalArgumentException` to contain a useful message... However, the javadocs for the method do specify some preconditions - you should look at those carefully.

Comment: Problem found: an issue with my code was creating an incorrect negative integer - not allowed to be passed to FileChannel.transferTo().